# “I haven't" VS "I have not"

Tags: past-tense

I have left home long time and not returned to home.
I can say

> I have not been home for long time.

But I think I can't say

> I haven't been home for long time.

Because "haven't" means something have not completed. "be home not completed"  sounds strange.

Comment: To me, *I haven't gone home for a long time* or *I haven't been home **in** a year* sounds better.  I don't know why, but I might be wrong then.

Comment: The only difference between **have not** and its contraction **haven't** is formality; contractions like **haven't** are considered less formal. But the meaning and usage are the same. If you can say one, then you can say the other.

Comment: You have a basic mistake, which you could have checked: **in a long time** and **for a long time**. have been is the present perfect of the verb be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between your sentences. The auxiliary verb "have" and the negative particle "not" can be contracted without changing the meaning, and only slightly changing the formality.

"Haven't" doesn't mean "not completed".

However the sentences are both wrong: "or **a** long time" or "in **a** long time"

Answer (score 0):

I can say, "I have never been in Dubai before" or "I haven't been in Dubai before".

Comment: Note that this question and answer are more than 3 years old, though if you want to add something to help other SE users in the future this is always welcome. I hope my edits captured what you meant to say.